# Creating a CubeGeometry equivilent using CSS3DRenderer

Tags: three.js, geometry, renderer

I am looking for sample code, that would show how one can create a cube (similar to `THREE.CubeGeometry`) in ThreeJS using `CSS3DRenderer`. Something like below

```
var my_cube = new **CSS3dCubeGeometry**( cube_width, cube_height, cube_depth)

var object = new THREE.CSS3DObject( my_cube );

scene.add( object );
```

`THREE.CSS3DObject` doesn't exist and I am looking for a potential implementation of it.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a cube with `CSS3DRenderer` like so:

```
// params
var r = Math.PI / 2;
var d = 50;
var pos = [ [ d, 0, 0 ], [ -d, 0, 0 ], [ 0, d, 0 ], [ 0, -d, 0 ], [ 0, 0, d ], [ 0, 0, -d ] ];
var rot = [ [ 0, r, 0 ], [ 0, -r, 0 ], [ -r, 0, 0 ], [ r, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ] ];

// cube
var cube = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add( cube );

// sides
for ( var i = 0; i < 6; i ++ ) {

    var element = document.createElement( 'div' );
    element.style.width = '100px';
    element.style.height = '100px';
    element.style.background = new THREE.Color( Math.random() * 0xffffff ).getStyle();
    element.style.opacity = '0.50';

    var object = new THREE.CSS3DObject( element );
    object.position.fromArray( pos[ i ] );
    object.rotation.fromArray( rot[ i ] );
    cube.add( object );

}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MdPrb/7

three.js r.64

Comment: Thanks WestLangley, this sample creates a cube of 100px,100px,100px. I would like to have both position and dimensions parametrized.

Comment: Please try, and if you have problems, make a new post with your additional requirements. I think you can figure this one out yourself, however. :-)