# can Three.js's CSS3DRenderer render meshes?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have been playing around with the CSS3DRenderer and was wondering if it's possible to render meshes. While browsing the available internet resources I came across a Stackoverflow question where cube geometry is explained([Creating a CubeGeometry equivilent using CSS3DRenderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850257/creating-a-cubegeometry-equivilent-using-css3drenderer)). In this example "THREE.Object3D()" is accessed. Since Object3D is available is it possible to make a standard three.js 3d object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could, but I think it would be too slow to be really usable...

Here are some tests that @WestLangley did last month:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63997063/Three/CSS3D/examples/css3d_geometry_birds.html
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63997063/Three/CSS3D/examples/css3d_performance.html
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63997063/Three/CSS3D/examples/css3d_morphtargets_horse.html

Comment: Cool. There not running so bad. One strange thing I noticed, i'm getting almost the same frame rate regardless of the size of the window.